# Insert string every Nth word

Tags: c, string, cpu-word, between

Add string between every Nth string.

My idea:

```
char *a = "one", *b = "two";

char *word = "Simple sentence containing some random words";
char result[200];


int len = strlen(word);
int spaces = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if(word[i] == ' ')
        spaces++;

    result[i] = word[i];

    if(spaces % 3 == 0)
    {
        //copy a to result
    }

    if(spaces % 4 == 0)
    {
        //copy b to result
    }

}
```

So after we're ready, result would look like this:

```
Simple sentence containing one some two random words
```

I've tried strcpy, strcat and I've struggled with it for some days now but I really don't seem to get the logic behind here. How to proceed?

Comment: You will need a different variable to index `result` than you use to index `word`, because after the first insertion, they won't match. For example `int j = 0;` so that `result[j++] = word[i];` Then try using a similar technique to copy each letter of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I came up with.  A detailed description of everything I did is provided in the comments for the code.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_OUTPUT_LENGTH 200

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* You can replace the words defined below ("one" and "two") with any words
  * you want to insert at the given positions.
  */
  char one[] = "one";
  char two[] = "two";

  char sentence[] = "Longer but still simple sentence containing even more words";
  char result[MAX_OUTPUT_LENGTH];


  int len = strlen(sentence);
  int spaces = 0;
  int k = 0; //See Weather Vane's comment for why you also need the variable k
  int skipUntilAnotherSpace = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
      if(sentence[i] == ' ') {
        spaces++;
        skipUntilAnotherSpace = 0; //See my explanation below for why this is done.
      }

      if (k == 0) {
        result[i] = sentence[i]; //Normally, we can use the variable "i" until our insertion
      } else {
        /* As Weather Vane's comment shows, after one insertion the positions you
        * need to grab from and insert to will change.  You cannot continue
        * to use "i". After the first insertion:
        * Sentence:
        * Simple sentence containing some random words
        *                            ^ position 27
        * Current value in result variable:
        * Simple sentence containing one [you want to insert here]
        *                                ^ position 31
        * So, we will need to insert into result at position k, and grab the info
        * from a different variable "i".
        */
        result[k] = sentence[i];
        //Increment k since it will not be incremented regularly in the for loop
        k++;
      }
      if((spaces % 3 == 0) && spaces != 0 && skipUntilAnotherSpace == 0)
      {
           int useVariableK = 0;
           if (spaces > 3) {
              /* Since spaces must already have been == 4, we have switched over
              to using variable K, so we must continue to do so */
              useVariableK = 1;
           }

           if(!useVariableK) {
           result[i] = ' '; //Add a space before we add the word "one"
           i++; //Increment i since we added the spaces

           int j;
           for (j = 0; j < strlen(one); j++) { //Add the word "one"
             result[i + j] = one[j];
           }
           //Increment the variable i the correct # of times since we added the word "one":
           i += (strlen (one));

           //Add a space after the word "one":
           result[i] = ' ';
           k = i + 1; //Set k = to i + 1 to account for the space we just added

           /* We need to revert back to where the variable "i" was before adding "one":

            We used the variable i to temporarily store the positions
            as we traversed across and added the word "one".  Then, we
            moved i back to the original position so we could access
            the correct position when using sentence[i] in the next iteration.

            Note that we need the +1 in the line below because we actually
            need to go back one more position than nessesary; when we re-enter
            the loop it will increment i to be +1 again! (sneaky)
           */
           i -= (strlen (one) + 1);

           /* Why we need the skipUntilAnotherSpace variable:
           We cannot simply increment the "spaces" variable after this; we need
           the number of spaces to conform to the number in the sentence, and
           just because we have more spaces in the result, it woudn't make sense
           to increment it for the sentence.

           However, if we leave it the same, then the next time we will enter
           this loop again since spaces == 3, and we don't want to enter this loop again;
           we have done our job already!

           So, we make sure not to enter the loop by setting the below variable
           to 1.  We do not enter the loop unless skipUntilAnotherSpace == 1.
           (If we even tried to increment the spaces variable, we would actually
            end up going into the next loop because spaces would = 4 ;) )

            Finally, we switch back skipUntilAnotherSpace to be 0 once
            another space is detected in the sentence.
           */
           skipUntilAnotherSpace = 1;
         } else {
           //Use variable K like we do if spaces == 4:
           /* Most of this loop is exactly identical to the previous one, except
           that we don't need another space since it was already added before when
           "one" was inserted, and we use the variable "k" instead of i. */
           int j;
           for (j = 0; j < strlen(one); j++) {
             result[k + j] = one[j];
           }
           k += (strlen (one));
           result[k] = ' ';
           k += 1;

           //spaces++;
           skipUntilAnotherSpace = 1;
         }
      }

      if((spaces % 4 == 0) && spaces != 0 && skipUntilAnotherSpace == 0)
      {
         /* Most of this loop is exactly identical to the previous one, except
         that we don't need another space since it was already added before when
         "one" was inserted, and we use the variable "k" instead of i. */
         int j;
         for (j = 0; j < strlen(two); j++) {
           result[k + j] = two[j];
         }
         k += (strlen (two));
         result[k] = ' ';
         k += 1;

         //spaces++;
         skipUntilAnotherSpace = 1;
      }

  }

  printf("%s.\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note**: See [Weather Vane's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) comment on this question to further understand why the variable `k` was necessary (I have also explained it in the comments, I just think Weather Vane's version is a little more concise).

The output produced by this code is:

```
Longer but still one simple two sentence containing one even more two words.
```

If you had changed the variables `one` and `two` to the values *"hello"* and *"goodbye"* respectively, the code would still be functional and produce:

```
Longer but still hello simple goodbye sentence containing hello even more goodbye words.
```

Basically, the code inserts the value in variable `one[]` every three words, and the value in variable `two[]` every four words in the sentence.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, this gets me started. However, the output will be incorrect if the sentence has more words. It should be every nth word, for the whole sentence - not just the first 3rd ad 4th words. How to proceed? I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: @jaked: You can change the sentence to be anything, given there is enough room for the output result.  For example, I changed my sentence to `char sentence[] = "Another random sentence containing other random stuff"`.  The output worked fine, and was not incorrect (the sentence had more words).  I was also able to insert the two words _anywhere else_ in the sentence using this approach.  For example, I changed `spaces == 3` and `spaces == 4` in both the first and second loops to `spaces == 2` and `spaces == 5`.  The output looked fine: `Simple sentence one containing some random two words`.

Comment: @jaked: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I meant if the input is: `Longer but still simple sentence containing more words`
and the output will be: `Longer but still WORD1 simple WORD2 sentence containing more WORD1 words`

Comment: Ah, I see.  I will look into using the modulus operator with this approach.

Comment: @jaked: I think I see what you mean.  Do you want, for example, WORD1 to appear every 3 words in the sentence, and WORD2 to appear every 4 words in the sentence?

Comment: Exactly! I've been trying to figure it out but with no success yet.

Comment: Then, if your input is: `Longer but still simple sentence containing even more words`, then the output should be `Longer but still WORD1 simple WORD2 sentence containing WORD1 even more WORD2 words`?

Comment: @jaked: Aha!  I did it.  Will edit the answer to conform to your requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with working down a string *character-by-character* and counting spaces (as long as you aggregate spaces, etc.), however, there is another approach to consider that may provide a bit more flexibility. Rather than searching for spaces, you can use `strtok` (in `string.h`) to *tokenize* your input string. Then, it is just a matter of counting *tokens* (words) and inserting your additions as the *nth* word (or words) at the appropriate position (index).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 512 };

int main (void) {

    char *w1 = "one", *w2 = "two";              /* replacement words   */
    int nth1 = 3, nth2 = 4;                     /* positions for w1/w2 */
    char line[MAXC] = "", *p = NULL, *delim = " \t.,;\n";
    char *fmt1 = "%s", *fmt2 = " %s";

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) { /* for each line read from stdin */
        int idx = 0;                        /* tokenize line with strtok */
        for (p = strtok (line, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            printf (!idx ? fmt1 : fmt2, p); idx++;    /* print token */
            if (idx == nth1) printf (fmt2, w1);   /* check and insert w1 */
            if (idx == nth2) printf (fmt2, w2);   /* and w2 in nth pos   */
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you can tailor the indexing to your needs. For instance you can increment the index `idx` after inserting the *nth* words to have them insert in sequence, etc...)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "Simple sentence containing some random words" | ./bin/replacenthword
Simple sentence containing one some two random words
```

Since you are not hardcoding the string to operate on, you can now replace the *nth1* or *nth2* word in any line you send it, in an entire file if you like, e.g.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/replcmt.txt
Simple sentence containing some random words
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Fewer words
That's all folks
```

**Example Use/Output w/File**

```
$ ./bin/replacenthword <dat/replcmt.txt
Simple sentence containing one some two random words
A quick brown one fox two jumps over the lazy dog
Fewer words
That's all folks one
```

If you only want to insert the *nth* word *if there is a following word*, then all you need do is change the order of test and print of each token.

```
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) { /* for each line read from stdin */
        int idx = 0;                        /* tokenize line with strtok */
        for (p = strtok (line, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            if (idx == nth1) printf (fmt2, w1);   /* check and insert w1 */
            if (idx == nth2) printf (fmt2, w2);   /* and w2 in nth pos   */
            printf (!idx ? fmt1 : fmt2, p); idx++;        /* print token */
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

Which would produce the same output, but omit replacement if `nth1` or fewer tokens (words) were present in the line, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/replacenthword <dat/replcmt.txt
...
That's all folks
```

Look over all the answers, and let me know if you have any questions.